# Is it possible to repeat an image (pattern) in SVG format in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, svg

```dart
final kBackgroundImage = Image.asset(
  'assets/images/bg.png',
  repeat: ImageRepeat.repeat,
  height: double.infinity,
  width: double.infinity,
);
```

To do something like this with a SVG background image?

Comment: Can you find any solution for repeat image in svg?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use flutter_svg_provider package to achieve the desired result. But keep in mind that the plugin is not actively maintained as of writing this answer.

Sample code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg_provider/flutter_svg_provider.dart' as svg_provider;

const svgPath = 'assets/sample_bg.svg';
void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(const RepeatativeSvgBackgroundExample());
}

class RepeatativeSvgBackgroundExample extends StatelessWidget {
  const RepeatativeSvgBackgroundExample({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.light(
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Svg Repeatative Background')),
        body: _HomePage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: double.infinity,
      width: double.infinity,
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
        image: DecorationImage(
            image: svg_provider.Svg(svgPath, size: Size.square(40)),
            repeat: ImageRepeat.repeat,
            fit: BoxFit.none),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

pubspec.yaml

```yaml
name: temp
description: A new Flutter project.

publish_to: "none"

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.19.3 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_svg: ^1.0.1
  flutter_svg_provider: ^1.0.3

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0

flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/sample_bg.svg

  uses-material-design: true
```

You can replace sample_bg.svg with your svg.

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Flutter doesn't officially supports SVG format, I saw few blogs and found that it causes performance issues. I tried it by myself using GridView and Flutter SVG package, and it lagged for a bit. So I think it is better to use PNG for repetitive background.

```
  List<Widget> _svgImages(int number) {
    List<Widget> svg = [];
    for (int i = 0; i <= number; i++) {
      svg.add(SvgPicture.asset(
        'assets/plane.svg',
        color: Colors.green,
      ));
    }
    return svg;
  }

GridView(
    gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
        maxCrossAxisExtent: 20,
        childAspectRatio: 1,
        crossAxisSpacing: 0,
        mainAxisSpacing: 0,
        ),
    children: _svgImages(200),
)
```